# How To Combine showModalDialog and Yes / No Button

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a Pop Up Dialog on SpreadsheetApp, which is displayed using htmlOutput. In this display I also want to include a link to open another link, as well as YES and NO buttons to trigger other functions if you select YES and close the dialog if you select NO.

After I tried, I couldn't carry out other functions after pressing the YES button.

```
 function showDialog() {
          var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Are You Sure to Process?</p><br><button onclick="handleYes()">YES</button><button onclick="handleNo()">NO</button>');

         SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
        } ;

function handleYes() {
         yesEffect() ;
         } ;
function handleNo() {
         google.script.host.close();
         };
function yesEffect() {
         const htmlOutput = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to Access Drive Home Page<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/home" target="_blank">OPEN DRIVE HOME PAGE </a></p>')
        .setWidth(300)
        .setHeight(200)
      
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'ACCESS DRIVE');

     } ;
```

Any suggestions for improvement?
Your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing script, it seems that in your script, the function of Google Apps Script is called from Javascript. In this case, `google.script.run` is used. And, in order to close the dialog, I think that you can directly use `google.script.host.close()` in the dialog. When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function showDialog() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Are You Sure to Process?</p><br><button onclick="google.script.run.handleYes()">YES</button><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">NO</button>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'CONFIRMATION');
}

function handleYes() {
  yesEffect();
}

function yesEffect() {
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to Access Drive Home Page<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/home" target="_blank">OPEN DRIVE HOME PAGE </a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(200)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'ACCESS DRIVE');
}
```

- By this modification, when "YES" button is clicked, a dialog of "ACCESS DRIVE!" is opened. When "NO" button is clicked, the dialog is closed.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Awesome. Very fast response. Thanks @Tanaike. It's work.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.